# Generic types in Java - advanced polymorphism

Tags: java, oop, generics, object, polymorphism

I have 3 simple classes as follows:

```
public class ElementA {}
public class ElementB extends ElementA {}
public class ElementC extends ElementB {}
```

Then if I want to create, for example, generic List which takes only subclasses of ElementA class I can declare it as:

```
List<? super ElementA> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then use it as follows:

```
list.add(new ElementA());
list.add(new ElementB());
list.add(new ElementC());
```

which is fine and can be compiled without errors. But I became confused if I want to store anything but not ElementC or ElementB or ElementA. I declare such List as follows:

```
List<? extends ElementC> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I can't use it at all because it can store only null values. Same thing happen when I declare List as (notice that I'm using class which is 'in the middle of family'):

```
List<? extends ElementB>
```

Why so?

Comment: Why would you expect `List<? extends ElementC> list = new ArrayList<>();` to store anything, you don't have any classes that extend ElementC ?

Comment: Please read the end of my question. I tried it even with Object class and still that List can store only null values

Comment: `List <? extends Object> list = new ArrayList <>();`  ?  

You should initialize your list with an element like so:
`List<? extends ElementB> list = new ArrayList<ElementC>();`

Comment: Java 7 does not require this.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) pretty much covers it.

Comment: you can create collection which store you object of given type, but you cant create collection which store you anything but given type. (unless you create your own collection). so when you created collection `List<? extends ElementC> list = new ArrayList<>();` it means you can put there anything which inherit ElementC, and of course null as null is special case

Comment: you should use extends rather that super in this case. List<? super ElementA> list = new ArrayList<>(); should be List<? extends ElementA> list = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `?` is not known at runtime. You have to substitute a concrete class/interface in order to be able to do what you want.

If you do this:

```
List<ElementA> list = new ArrayList<ElementA>();
```

you are fine since `ElementB` **is an** `ElementA` at the same time. Same stands for `ElementC`.

`List<? extends ElementA>` makes sense if you for example declare it in a class and in a subclass you can substitute something concrete as the type parameter. Clumsy example:

```
public class SomeClass<T> {
    private List<? extends T> list;

    public void setList(List<? extends T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

public class SomeConcreteClass extends SomeClass<Integer> {

    public void doSomething() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        setList(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<ElementA>` accepts instances of `ElementA`, `ElementB`, and `Element C`.

`List<ElementB>` accepts instances of `ElementB` and `Element C`.

`List<ElementC>` accepts instances of `ElementC`.

There is no reason for the wildcard in your examples.

`List<? super ElementA>` means a List of some type which is `ElementA` or a superclass.

`List<? extends ElementB>` means a List of some type which is a subclass of `ElementB`. If you *get* an element it will be `ElementB` or a subclass, but it doesn't know what the class is, so it can't be sure the element you add is of the right type, since it is unknown (though it does know it to be a subclass of `ElementB`).

There are uses for wildcard, but your example is not one of them.

Comment: Regarding `List<? super ElementA>` take a look at [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard%20instantiation?): "The wildcard parameterized type `Comparator<? super String>` is the family of all instantiations of the `Comparator` interface for type argument types that are **supertypes** of `String`". You seem to be stating the opposite.

Comment: "`List<? extends ElementB>` means a List of some type which is a subclass of `ElementB`" -- Actually, it can be a List of `ElementB` as well; it's not restricted to _subclasses_ of `ElementB`.

Comment: Good catch. Typo on my part. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `List` like this

```
List<? extends ElementC> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

but let's say, because it's still valid that you got the `List` like this

```
List<? extends ElementC> list = getElementCSubclassList(); // declared as returning a `List<ElementCSubclass>`
```

Now the compiler cannot know that your `list` object contains `ElementCSubclass` objects, it can only be sure that it contains *some* type of `ElementC`. As such, it can't let you use any methods that expect the actual generic type.

Imagine

```
public class ElementCSubclass1 extends ElementC {}
public class ElementCSubclass2 extends ElementC {}
...
List<? extends ElementC> list = getElementCSubclass1List(); // declared as returning a `List<ElementCSubclass1>`

list.add(new ElementCSubclass2()); // this would immediately have to fail
```

Compiler does this so that the previous situation never occurs.